# dfs.block.size for Local hadoop jobs ?

Tags: java, hadoop, filesize

I want to run a hadoop unit test, using the local filesystem mode...  I would ideally like to see several part-m-* files written out to disk (rather than just 1).  However, since it just a test, I dont want to process 64M of data (the default size is ~64megs per block, i believe).

In distributed mode we can set this using

```
dfs.block.size
```

I am wondering wether there a way that i can get my local file system to write small part-m files out, i.e. so that my unit test will mimic the contents of large scale data with several (albeit very small) files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input format can handle splitable files (see the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.isSplitable(JobContext, Path)` method), you can amend the input split size to process a smaller file with multi mappers (i'm going to assume you're using the new API mapreduce package):

For example, if you're using the `TextInputFormat` (or most input formats that extend `FileInputFormat`), you can call the static util methods:

- `FileInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(Job, long)`
- `FileInputFormat.setMinInputSplitSize(Job, long)`

The long argument is the size of the split in bytes, so just set to you're desired size

Under the hood, these methods set the following job configuration properties:

- `mapred.min.split.size`
- `mapred.max.split.size`

Final note, some input formats may override the `FileInputFormat.getFormatMinSplitSize()` method (which defaults to 1 byte for `FileInputFormat`), so be weay if you set a value and hadoop is appearing to ignore it.

A final point - have you considered MRUnit http://incubator.apache.org/mrunit/ for actual 'unit' testing of your MR code?

Answer (score 0):

try doing this it will work

```
hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=16777216 -put 25090206.P .
```